# Have key store file and password - how can I access my ETH without Mist/Geth

Tags: cpp-ethereum

Maybe a Noob question. I have the text file from the keystore folder. I have the password. How can I access my funds without using Mist/Geth? These are not working on my computer. Is there an online option to import the wallet. If I input the strings from the file in myetherwallet.com it will only show empty other accounts. Also I did not need to enter my password. Where can I find the encrypted key string in the file.

Comment: "These are not working on my computer." I'd like to know more about this. Why are they not working?

Answer (score 2):

Just upload the entire keystore file under "Upload JSON" on the Send Transaction tab. It is not a text file, it is a JSON file, just with no labeled extension. Then it will ask for your password.